# javafx: How do I hide the "drop down arrow" in a TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, tree, treeview, scenebuilder

Hope everyone is doing well.

My question is pretty basic: How do I make the arrow at the root of a TreeView hidden, if it's possible? A good example of what I want to achieve can be seen in Windows Event Viewer.

[image]

While my javafx application looks like the image below

[image]

By default, that arrow next to vehicles is present.

I read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html), but I only found .showRoot(), which doesn't achieve what I want. I would really appreciate any input, even if it's a cheat way to do it (using the x-offset property crossed my mind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is part of the [`disclosureNode`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html#disclosureNodeProperty) of the `TreeCell`. When not specified it is the responsibility of the `TreeCell`'s skin to provide a default disclosure node (e.g. the triangle). This is stated by the property-setter documentation:

> The node to use as the "disclosure" triangle, or toggle, used for expanding and collapsing items. This is only used in the case of an item in the tree which contains child items. If not specified, the TreeCell's Skin implementation is responsible for providing a default disclosure node.

Yet looking at the `TreeCellSkin` it appears it *does not* provide the default disclosure node. Instead, this seems to be handled by the `TreeViewSkin` (in both JavaFX 8 and JavaFX 11). Looking at the implementation the default disclosure node is a `StackPane` with a child `StackPane` that functions as the actual arrow. Their style class is `tree-disclosure-node` and `arrow`, respectively. Note that this doesn't appear documented anywhere, including the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

The easiest and least bug-prone method to hiding the root disclosure node is, in my opinion, to use CSS. The only problem here is that `TreeCell` provides no way to target only the root cell. But this can still be accomplished by subclassing `TreeCell` and providing our own [`PseudoClass`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html). Then we set the [`cellFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#cellFactoryProperty) on our `TreeView`.

To set the graphic of the root set the [`TreeItem.graphic`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#graphicProperty) property of the root `TreeItem`.

---

**CustomTreeCell**

```
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class CustomTreeCell<T> extends TreeCell<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass ROOT = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("root");

    public static <T> Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>> forTreeView() {
        return treeView -> new CustomTreeCell<>();
    }

    public CustomTreeCell() {
        getStyleClass().add("custom-tree-cell");

        InvalidationListener listener = observable -> {
            boolean isRoot = getTreeView() != null && getTreeItem() == getTreeView().getRoot();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(ROOT, isRoot);
        };

        treeViewProperty().addListener(listener);
        treeItemProperty().addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            graphicProperty().unbind();
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString()); // Really only works if item is a String. Change as needed.
            graphicProperty().bind(getTreeItem().graphicProperty());
        }
    }

}
```

**CSS File**

```css
.custom-tree-cell:root .tree-disclosure-node,
.custom-tree-cell:root .arrow {

    -fx-min-width: 0;
    -fx-pref-width: 0;
    -fx-max-width: 0;

    -fx-min-height: 0;
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
    -fx-max-height: 0;

}

/* Related to question asked in the comments by OP */
.custom-tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 L 0 8 L 8 5 L 0 2 Z";
}
```

*Some notes:*

1. *Since I bound the `TreeCell.graphic` property to the `TreeItem.graphic` property in my cell implementation you won't be able to set the graphic from CSS. You can modify this to simply set the graphic, rather than bind, in order to enable that functionality. Then you won't have to set the graphic of the root `TreeItem` through code but could do `.custom-tree-cell:root { -fx-graphic: ...; }`.*
2. *This doesn't remove the disclosure node, it just makes it have no width and no height.*
3. *This solution relies on implementation details; be careful when changing versions of JavaFX. I only tried this on JavaFX 11.0.2 but I believe it should work for JavaFX 8 as well.*

Comment: This is an incredible answer. Thank you so much! Given that you understand this, I want to ask, do you also know of a way to change the styling of the disclosure triangle so that it is not a solid shape, but looks more like the event viewer example from my question, like an arrow ">", or access to a .setStyle() of some kind for the triangle?

Comment: It's not a perfect replication but I added more to the CSS file. I also can't promise the value of `-fx-shape` is proper as I don't have much experience with SVG paths; it does approximate `>`, however.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**MyTreeCellSkin.java**

```
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeCellSkin;

public class MyTreeCellSkin<T> extends TreeCellSkin<T> {

    public MyTreeCellSkin(TreeCell<T> control) {
        super(control);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);

        TreeView<T> tree = getSkinnable().getTreeView();

        int level = tree.getTreeItemLevel(getSkinnable().getTreeItem());
        if (!tree.isShowRoot()) {
            level--;
        }
        double leftMargin = getIndent() * level;

        x += leftMargin;

        double disclosureWidth = 18;

        final int padding = 3;
        // x += disclosureWidth + padding;
        x += 3;

        w -= (leftMargin + disclosureWidth + padding);

        layoutLabelInArea(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

**CustomTreeCell.java**

```
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;

public class CustomTreeCell<T> extends TreeCell<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass ROOT = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("root");

    public CustomTreeCell() {
        getStyleClass().add("custom-tree-cell");

        InvalidationListener listener = observable -> {
            boolean isRoot = getTreeView() != null && getTreeItem() == getTreeView().getRoot();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(ROOT, isRoot);
        };

        treeViewProperty().addListener(listener);
        treeItemProperty().addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            graphicProperty().unbind();
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());
            graphicProperty().bind(getTreeItem().graphicProperty());
        }
    }

}
```

**main.java**

```
treeView.setCellFactory(param -> {
           CustomTreeCell<String> treeCell = new CustomTreeCell<>();
           treeCell.setSkin(new MyTreeCellSkin<>(treeCell));
           return treeCell;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX 8 all you need is to update two style classes within extended TreeCell.

[image]

In my TreeCell constructor i used a StackPane as graphic and set style with inverted padding value.

```
    stackPane.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 0 0 -5;");
        
// update styles in updateItem method

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Group item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
    getStyleClass().remove("just-core-tree-cell");
    getStyleClass().remove("core-leaf-tree-cell");
            
    if (empty || null == item) {
      return;
    }

// i coded a simple method to check if parent item is the root item
// but you can do same with a getTreeItem() parent check instead

    boolean isCoreGroup = item.isParentRoot();
    boolean isLeaf = item.isLeaf();

    if (isCoreGroup && isLeaf) {
                getStyleClass().add("core-leaf-tree-cell");
            }
    
    if (isCoreGroup && !isLeaf) {
                getStyleClass().add("just-core-tree-cell");
            }

 // Do some other graphical updates on the stack pane...
    setGraphic(this.stackPane);
 // Set different icon depending on the TreeItem's expanded state as indicator
    getTreeItem().setGraphic(iconExpanded);
```

**In CSS-Style-File set padding values as follow**

```
            .tree-cell {
                -fx-indent: 8.0;
                -fx-padding: 0.0 2.0 0.0 -10.0;
            }
            
            /* (leafs) indent compensation to the left space*/
            .core-leaf-tree-cell {
/* because +18 is the hard coded left space padding, BUG: JDKJDK-8180646
 * TreeView renders TreeCells with superfluous indentation if disclosure 
 * node is not visible or smaller than 18px in width */
                -fx-padding: 0 2px 0 -21px;
            }
            
            .just-core-tree-cell{
                -fx-padding: 0 2px 0 3px;
            }
            
            .just-core-tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node, .just-core-tree-cell .arrow, .just-core-tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow
                {
                -fx-rotate: 0;
                -fx-scale-shape: true;
                -fx-min-width: 0;
                -fx-pref-width: 0;
                -fx-max-width: 0;
                -fx-min-height: 0;
                -fx-pref-height: 0;
                -fx-max-height: 0;
            }
```